# OpenVPN: Transporting a connection from that 'other' OS?

Tags: windows, openvpn, remote-access

After finally making the change from windows to Ubuntu, one needed function remains unfulfilled - a needed connection via OpenVPN to a distant location.

I have all the files from the previously working configuration that match those at the other end, but have not been able to get the right info into the right places to make it work.

Posting at the OpenVPN forum has brought only nastiness in return from folks who use that place to promote their commercial agendas.

Given the state of things at present, visiting that location to make changes is not a viable option.

I am hoping very much that someone else here has made this change before & will kindly guide me so that I may have a working connection again.

Thanks for any helpful replies.

Comment: You had OpenVNC working. Which computer did you migrate, the server, the client, both? I suggest you tell us just what you are doing now and how it fails. Also, I'm a bit lost, openvnc on Ubuntu? And you added the _openvpn_ tag ...

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply Eduardo Trápani.

Comment: I hesitated to say too much at 1st because of the verbal thrashing I got at the other place for daring to ask such a question at all !!
I connect to a distant Linux server that was set up a few years ago and which I currently cannot visit in person.
My prior PC at home ran windows with OpenVPN installed & working...it is the replacement for that PC which now has Ubuntu 18.04 and which I am trying to connect from.

Comment: I tried setting it up using the original .OVPN file via the Network Manager which has an option for that as well as importing an existing configuration & it failed instantly.
I then also tried an app called Pritunl which had the same result.
Lastly I tried a Q&A type of script suggested to me which created a new .OVPN file, but since it did not have the correct/matching security data, it too failed.
I have the various files with the data, but in the years between my notes have been lost & I do not know which bits to place in which fields.

Comment: Having tried many times I am hoping that someone may clarify the steps to re-use this connection from my new PC.
Thanks for any further help.

Comment: My bad for getting the name/acronym wrong - sorry - and thanks for correcting me !!

Comment: suggest you [edit] your question to remove all editorial material and clearly explain the question. Which seems to be - I used to connect using OpenVPN to an Ubuntu server from a windows machine. Now I want to connect to the same server using an Ubuntu machine. How do I do that.

Comment: Organic Marble, your suggestion is not accurate, but thanks for showing me that this was not the right place to ask for this help - which reminded me to seek elsewhere for greater success.

Answer (score 0):

I posted my query here as I thought it was as simple as closing the gap in moving an OpenVPN connection from windows to Ubuntu.
That idea proved to be incorrect.
It turns out that it is a version mismatch between what Ubuntu is using now vs. what the PC at the distant location is using, that is an older version which I must travel there to update manually.
Since I cannot travel there in the present craziness, it must wait for me to do that.

In the meantime it is fortunate that I had the foresight to install the free version of Anydesk there such that I can access all EXCEPT for the OpenVPN server, and I am still able to fire up the old windows box here if I desperately need to use that connection.

The info I needed to identify that mismatch was provided at the server s/w site by a user who knew the correct & specific things to check in finding why my present OS could not log in.

Oversimplification=>
It is just too new !!